# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addMethod' of undefined in jquery validate

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Hi I am using `jQuery JavaScript Library v1.10.2` and `jQuery Validation Plugin 1.11.1` and get the above error. 
Code

```
$.validator.addMethod("fnType", function (value, element) {
    if (element.value == "-1") { return false; } else {return true;}
}, "Please select Type");
```

The rest of the code is for jquery validation. The above code is inside `$(document).ready` and within that inside `$("#button").click`.

Note: I was using `jQuery JavaScript Library v1.4.4` earlier and upgraded to these versions to use jquery validate. I am stuck with this from morning. Please help/advise.

EDIT:
Here is the complete code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    OnPageLoad();

    $("#ctl00_MainContentHolder_SubmitButton").click(function () {
        ValidatePage();
        if ($("#aspnetForm").valid()) {
            if (FormValidation()) {
                __doPostBack("Submit", "");
            }
        }
    });
});

function ValidatePage() {
    $.validator.addMethod("fnType", function (value, element) {
        if (element.value == "-1") { return false; } else {return true;}
    }, "Please select Type");

    $("#aspnetForm").validate({
        ignore:":hidden",
        rules: 
        {
            <%=Type.UniqueID %>: { required: true, fnType:true },
        }, 
        messages: 
        {
            <%=Type.UniqueID %>:{ required: "Type is required" },
        },
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
           error.appendTo('#ctl00_MainContentHolder_errorLabelTop');
        },
        wrapper: 'li'
    });
}
```

In the master page I have these in the same order

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Script/JQuery/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Script/JQuery/jquery.validate.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Script/CustomScript/CustomScript.js"></script>
```

EDIT: Here is the HTML code

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <label id="errorLabelTop" runat="server" class="ResponseText"></label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width:130px;">
            Scheme Type<span class="RedMainText" style="font-size:12px;"><sup>*</sup></span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select id="schemeType" runat="server" class="InputText" >
            <option value="-1">--Select--</option>
            <option value="Home3">Home 3 Monthly</option>
            <option value="Home6">Home 6 Monthly</option>
            <option value="Practice3">Practice 3 Monthly</option>
            <option value="Practice6">Practice 6 Monthly</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Show the complete JavaScript code as well as the HTML markup.

Comment: @Sparky I have edited my question providing the code. HTML for the `Type` is simple html select with `runat=server`

Comment: If the _rendered_ HTML is that simple, then it would be no trouble for you to actually show it.  (It's relevant to how you assign the rules.)

Answer (score 4):

Your code:

```
rules: {
    <%=Type.UniqueID %>: { required: true, fnType:true },
}
```

You cannot assign rules to the `id` of the `input`.  You must assign them only using the `name` attribute.  Also, remove any trailing commas if you want this to work in older versions of IE.

```
rules: {
    myField: {
        required: true,
        fnType: true 
    }
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<input name="myField" ...
```

Demo that shows the validation plugin will not work with `id`:  http://jsfiddle.net/hmBjY/

Demo that shows the validation plugin working with `name`:  http://jsfiddle.net/NKCg9/1/

---

Also, your code:

```
function ValidatePage() {

    $.validator.addMethod( ....

    $("#aspnetForm").validate({ ....
```

These methods do not go inside a function or a `click` handler for repeated calls.  The `click` is automatically captured by the plugin.  **These methods are only used for *initialization* so you call them *once* in the DOM ready event handler**...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $.validator.addMethod( ....

    $("#aspnetForm").validate({ ....
```

Comment: Sorry about the trailing commas my mistake it is not in the original code. But I am surprised to know that, rules cannot be applied to id of the input because I have similar bit working in other pages

Comment: @hima, The jQuery Validate plugin can be assigned rules in many different ways, so perhaps you've also used inline HTML5 validation, which it can pick up.  Since you've refused to show your _rendered_ HTML, I have no idea.

Comment: this is my html code: `<select id="Type" runat="server" class="InputText" onchange="EnableShipment();">                                                                <option value="-1">--Select--</option>                                                                <option value="Home3">Home 3 Monthly</option></select>`

Comment: @hima... as previously requested, edit the _rendered_ HTML code into your OP.  And without a `name` attribute, the plugin **will not** operate properly: http://jsfiddle.net/hmBjY/

Comment: I can see that it is not working in jsfiddle you ahve provided, but I have code working with only the id. I never give name to html/asp .net controls and till now everything seems to work fine.

Comment: @hima, that is impossible as proven by [my jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hmBjY/).  However, there are isolated cases where you can assign a rule (using other methods) to a field without a `name`, but that breaks when there's more than one field.  See broken:  http://jsfiddle.net/hmBjY/2/

Comment: thanks a ton for the useful input. Still my code works but the problem is with jquery files. I have a datepicker and the related files in the same page so there is a conflict in js files. I will upgrade all the files to latest versions and give a try. Thank you once again.

Comment: as suspected the js files were causing the problem and there was no problem with referring the ids of elements. Thank you for your help

Comment: @hima, if you'd simply show your HTML, I can demonstrate why you only _think_ declaring rules by `id` is no problem.

Answer (score -2):

Apparently I found out what was causing the problem after banging my head for a day on and off. I have jquery `Datepicker` in my webpage and I was using `jquery-ui js/css v1.8.6` while the jquery file was `v1.10.2`. This resulted in conflict and after upgrading `jquery-ui` to `v1.10.3` the above mentioned error no longer existed. This means that there was no error in the code. And another important thing to note is that, name attribute is a must for the elements for jquery validation.But it appears that for elements with runat="server", their id can be used in this manner <%=yourid.UniqueID%>  in jquery validation. All this is happening in master page and content page case.

thank you for all the useful contributions in the form of comments and answers.

Comment: **Reader beware**: This answer contains serious misinformation. You absolutely **cannot** _"safely refer to id of the element"_ in jQuery Validation's `.validate()` method. ~ [As per documentation: _"The name attribute is 'required' for input elements, the validation plugin doesn't work without it."_](http://jqueryvalidation.org/reference/)

Comment: See this jsFiddle which clearly shows that you cannot use `id` to declare rules within `.validate()`: http://jsfiddle.net/nMwqp

Comment: See this jsFiddle which demonstrates what the OP is likely observing on his page. Notice that validation is broken on all fields except the first: http://jsfiddle.net/DgMgf

Comment: If you need to declare rules by `id`, there are other methods, but you still **must** have a unique `name` attribute on every element.  See:  http://jsfiddle.net/QhasW/

Comment: @Sparky I still agree with all your jsfiddle examples but I have to say I have code working with only id. Might be the master pages that is making it work. How can I reproduce master page scenario in jsfiddle. the above posted code is the exact code I have in my page with the same id. I have edited my question to show html code.

Comment: If you still don't believe it, try adding more than one field to the form and tell me if it still works.  [I guess not](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19003870/594235).

Comment: @Sparky for your information I have 20+ fields in one page and none of them have name other than the ones with no `runat=server`.

Comment: If it's all working so well without `name` attributes, then why did you accept this answer?  http://stackoverflow.com/q/19003870/594235

Comment: I hope you realize that your _rendered_ HTML code is not the same as the code you've uploaded to your server.  The plugin only "sees" the _rendered_ HTML as it appears in the browser.

Comment: @Sparky please read my comment above(5th comment). It is in the master page. how can I reproduce master page? And after seeking answer here `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19003870/how-to-refer-html-element-in-jquery-validation-in-content-page` I realised that client side fields always need name attribute but server side fields can do without name. I accepted the answer because it solved my problem which is why SO is for

Comment: Server-side code means absolutely **nothing** to JavaScript because JavaScript is **client**-side code.  That's why I repeatedly asked you to "show the ***rendered*** HTML markup".