# How to refer html element in jquery validation in content page

Tags: html, jquery-validate

I have master and content page in asp .net web application. In my content page I am doing jquery validation. I have html element without `runat="server"` and I don't know how to refer to this id in jquery validation.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Title
        </td>
        <td>
            <select id="nameTitle" runat="server" class="InputText">
                <option value="-1">--Select--</option>
                <option value="Mr.">Mr</option>
                <option value="Mrs.">Mrs</option>
                <option value="Miss.">Miss</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="130px">
            First Name:<span class="RedMainText"><sup>*</sup></span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="firstName" class="InputText" size="30" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="130px">
            Surname:<span class="RedMainText"><sup>*</sup></span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="surname" class="InputText" size="30" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Jquery validation:

```
rules: 
{
    <%=nameTitle.UniqueID %>: { required: true },
    firstName: { required: true },
    surname: { required: true }
}, 
messages: 
{
    <%=nameTitle.UniqueID %>: { required: "Title is required" },
    firstName: { required: "First Name is required" },
    surname: { required: "Surname is required" }
}
```

Here `firstName` and `lastName` are not validated while `nameTitle` is validated. How to refer them? please advise.

Comment: [Again, you **must** use the `name` attribute!](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18962679/594235)

Comment: @Sparky I agree name is required but you please note that nameTitle does not have name and it works as expected with just the id.

Comment: Please show me a jsFiddle demo proving what you claim.  I've shown you examples and I've shown you the official documentation.  None of it changes the fact that this plugin **absolutely requires** a `name` attribute to keep track of inputs.  Now I can only refer you to the source code of the plugin itself: http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After taking a quick look at the [API Documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate) it appears to me that the `firstName` / `surname` items are supposed to link to the `Name` of an element

Could you please try it after setting the inputs up like so:

```
<input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName" class="InputText" size="30" />
<input type="text" id="surname" name="surname" class="InputText" size="30" />
```

Comment: @hima, exactly what I've been trying to tell you [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18962679/594235) and in the comments [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18981812/594235)

Answer (score 1):

for writhing jquery-validate rules you should use name of elements not their ids!

set name for your elements and then use the name:

```
<select name="nameOfTitle" id="nameTitle" runat="server" class="InputText">
            <option value="-1">--Select--</option>
            <option value="Mr.">Mr</option>
            <option value="Mrs.">Mrs</option>
            <option value="Miss.">Miss</option>
</select>
```

and in jquery validate use:

```
rules: 
{
    nameOfTitle: { required: true },
}, 
messages: 
{
    nameOfTitle: { required: "Title is required" },
}
```

you should do the same for your other inputs as well.